# consume SOAP web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

How do I consume this SOAP web service? how do I add the request header?

https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/ManagedPaymentService/test/managedCreditCardPayment.asmx?op=CreateCustomer

---

**REF**: http://www.eway.com.au/Developer/eway-api/token-payments.aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest way is to use .NET's built-in support.

In Visual Studio, right click on your project references and 'Add Service Reference'. Give it the service URL https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/ManagedPaymentService/managedCreditCardPayment.asmx and it will generate a proxy class for you that will do all the work. You can then just e.g.

```
var client = new eWayServiceReference.managedCreditCardPaymentSoapClient();
client.CreateCustomer(...);
```

Alternatively you can generate the proxy class from a VS command prompt using [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).

Comment: This is now also possible to do in .Net Core RC2. see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/25/announcing-wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-rc2-and-asp-net-core-rc2/