# Consume web service in ASP.Net, not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, asmx

I am looking for a web service ASP.Net (C#) solution that can consume the attached request, it must be done in code behind, due to the header records:

```
POST http://training.maxmoney.co.za/MaxAdmin/web_services/maxmoney/ HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: http://training.maxmoney.co.za/MaxAdmin/web_services/maxmoney/ConnectionTest
Username: albatross_soap
Password: @1B@tr0$$
Content-Type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
Host: training.maxmoney.co.za
Content-Length: 1227
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:max="http://training.maxmoney.co.za/webservices/maxmoney.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-E033FC91FFC6A82CA915397704062061">
                <wsse:Username>albatross_soap</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">@1B@tr0$$</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">gNpe7bc1ArfIL0A6pAvYUQ==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2018-10-17T10:00:06.205Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <max:connectionTest>
         <iGIDCode>910821</iGIDCode>
         <iMleAPIKey>4QWPiKbK4k7kvSuRAu1vrr2Mtxs</iMleAPIKey>
         <iCustomID/>
         <iCustomCode/>
      </max:connectionTest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Reply is:

> ReplyCode (4 char) (0000 - Success)
>
> ReplyStr (date & Time)

I have tried to consume it using the below:

```
string xml = doc.ToString();
string url = "http://training.maxmoney.co.za/MaxAdmin/web_services/maxmoney/";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
string backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(backstr);
sr.Close();
res.Close();
```

But I get dosument does not exist error,
The reply code needs to be :

> ReplyCode: 0000
>
> ReplyStr : (Current Date time)

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio to work on this? if so have you tried the built-in functionality to consume soap services? you can read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284269/consume-soap-web-service

Comment: Hi, I have but it cant take the link for the wsdl file because there are headers.